# Grant tracking has stopped after upgrade

Tags: civigrant

I have upgraded to the last version (now 5.63.2) from 5.57 and the tracking of grants has stopped.
We receive grant applications from a webform with civicrm integrated. The website uses Backdrop. All modules and core system are updated.

After the upgrade we can't see the Grants tab in the webform civicrm processing section.

The extension is enabled in the extensions page, but in the Components page there exists all the other options (to enable the other components) but I don't see the option to enable Civigrant.

Any advice would be appreciated,

Andrés

Answer (score 3):

CiviGrant recently moved from a component to an extension. It is normal and expected that you can see it in "Manage Extensions" but it is no longer listed in "Components".

The Drupal versions of Webform-CiviCRM were updated to accommodate this change, however the Backdrop version is, AFAIK, not maintained by anyone. It would need a version of this PR: https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/721

Comment: Agreed re: webform_civicrm for Backdrop - Jack from Palante Tech was maintaining it but they no longer do web development work.

Comment: The Backdrop version has been updated at this point and is being maintained by @herbdool.